# How to Cache user role details in a Spring restful webservice?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ehcache, spring-rest

In an application with Spring rest, once the user is authenticated I get user role details from an external system. I need to cache it in my application instead of hitting the external system for each request. What is the best way to cache it in my system and refresh it in a timely manner. Can I use Ehcache or any other cache framework or just normal HttpSession?

Comment: At least show some code of your approach.

Comment: Using JWT would remove that requirement as roles would be included in the token.

Comment: Yes just include User basic details in JWT, again you can get by decoding the JWT

Comment: It is not only user role details there are some details also, I want to cache it server side and don't want to send it to browser using jwt.